# One user answers all questions or tag monopoly

Tags: discussion, tags, reputation

There are some users at Stack Overflow who answer all questions with some special tag almost 24/7. They give in 5 mins all the possible options in their answer (and for this tag not many options are possible). So there are very small chances to give an answer after this user. I know there is a limit of 200 reputation points per day. It looks like this limit doesn't stop them. My question is what are limits for such superusers?

Comment: And what's the problem? Sounds like an amazing user.

Comment: What's stopping you? You could try to write better answers. Provide more details and rationales, give better examples, quote authorities on the topic and so on.

Comment: How would the internet become a better place if we limited this user?

Comment: Sounds like a dream come true.

Comment: Would his name happen to rhyme with "Bon Beet"?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I looked at the last 10 or so answered questions in that tag. **3** of them were answered by the same low rep user (hence not the one you mean), **2** of them were answered by the same high rep user (that may or may not be the one you mean), other than that they were answered by a whole bunch of people. So, I can only conclude that you are very exaggerating.

Comment: I bet most of the questions they answer are duplicates, unclear, lacking minimal examples, or in any other way not helpful for future visitors. Just vote to close those questions appropriately.

Comment: The problem is that other users can't earn any reputation points on this tag. Normally you can decide which answer is better by upvoting but in this case, all answers are taken by one user. Another problem that easy questions are also taken and new users can't answer them.

Comment: I have also read other posts about addiction to SO and I don't think that is very healthy to spend the whole day answering questions.

Comment: @MykolaZotko I don't know why it's your problem though. Reputation is just virtual cookies, why are you so concerned about it?

Comment: @DonThousand There are too many users and too few good questions so other users would also like to have some fun and earn those virtual cookies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> My question is what are limits for such a superuser?

There aren't any. As long as your answers are consistently judged by the community (via votes) to be of high quality, no rate or post limits are set for users.

Low reputation users have timed post limits (see [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) for reference), and if answers are consistently judged as poor one might run into the automated post ban, but that is it.